# Filetype wildcard multiple periods OSX

Tags: wxpython

Is there a way to specify a wildcard string for a `wx.FileDialog` that operates nicely if that wildcard has two periods in it? I'd like for it to work sensibly for files that end with, say, `.abc.xml`.

My current wildcard string looks like `"ABC Files (*.abc.xml)|*.abc.xml"`, but am getting grayed-out files of that type and suggestions for files I'm trying to save like `Filename.abc.xml.abc.xml`.

Thanks!